# Resize a JLayeredPane based on user's input

Tags: java, swing

I'm developping a sprite editor. I have a class that extends JPanel, in that class, I use a JLayeredPane as a container. On the bottom layer, there is a JLabel with an ImageIcon and on the top Layer there is a JPanel where I have drawn a grid. When the code is ran, I make some basic math to set the JLayeredPane's prefered size to be equal to about 85% of the height of the screen resolution.

My problem is that when the user wants a new canvas to draw on it, I ask with a JOptionPane the user the size of the canvas he wants. Then I call my class constructor to create a new canvas with the specified size. After that I apply the methods revalidate() and repaint() on the canvas. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. In addition, when I try to get the width and the height of my canvas, it gives 0 for both. However, when I set the size by myself directly into the code, it works well. Therefore, I would like to know how can I update the size of a JLayeredPane ?

[On start with a size of 85% of the screen resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhFJw.png)
[When I set the size to 640x640 directly inside my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJduj.png)
[When I answer the JOptionPane with a size of 640x640, the grid has been adapted to the asking size. However, it's not the case for the JLayeredPane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y40NP.png)

Comment: So you've got a bug in code you're not showing us -- ask yourself, how can we help in this situation? Please create and post a decent [mcve] so that you can get a decent answer.

Comment: *"I use a JLayeredPane as a container"* - why? Based on you description, it would be simpler to just use a `GridLayout` or something and get the layout done for free

Comment: @MadProgrammer JLayeredPane allows me to have a transparent grid on top of the canvas.

Comment: @LegendaryThierry Could do the same thing with a transparent `JPanel`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I use JLayeredPane like that : First Layer : imageLabel representing the canvas. Second Layer : Transparent JPanel where I have drawn a grid on it with paintComponent.

Comment: Okay two, things. One, you can do it without the `JLayeredPane`, instead using two components, one laid out on top of the other OR you can apply a layout manager to `JLayeredPane` and get the layout for free

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't understand why you want to apply a layout manager to JLayeredPane. Would you do something like : setLayout(null) ?

Comment: @LegendaryThierry Because that's what you're trying to do, you trying to layout out the components in the container, based on there preferred size, essentially this is the role of a layout manager. Rather the re-inventing the wheel, you should make use of the functionality which is available to you. Also `revalidate` deals with the layout management API

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's interesting. However, I thought that the use of the method setBounds was good enough to size the components. :/

Comment: @LegendaryThierry Without more context, it's difficult to say what might be going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context, it's impossible to know what's going wrong with your code.

However, personally, I'd stop trying to reinvent the wheel and make use of the available layout management API to provide you with the support you need.

There's a number of ways you could approach the problem. Personally I'd wrap the rendering of the grid and the image up into a single component, but that's me. In that case, you wouldn't need the `JLayeredPane`.

Let's, for the moment, assume that the `JLayeredPane` is non-negotiable.  I'd then apply a layout manager to the `JLayeredPane`, this makes interaction with the two other components (image and grid) simpler, as the layout manager takes over control.  Because you want them overlaid onto of each other, I'd be tempted to use a `GridBagLayout`.

The problem here then becomes keeping the two component's sizes in sync with each other.  To this end, I'd use `setPreferredSize` to change the size dynamically.

*"insert internal screaming"* - Any time I see `setPreferredSize` it sets of alarm bells.  In this case, again, I'd fall back to using a single component and provide a "sizing" mechanism which worked with `getPreferredSize`, but at the end of day, this is moving us in the same direction.

For laying out the `JLayeredPane` at 85% height of the parent container, again, `GridBagLayout` would be my preferred choice.

The following example lays the `JLayeredPane` in such away as it will want to fill the available space of the parent container (up to 85% of the available height).  It then allows the image and grid components to automatically position themselves within side this area.

[image: Default size]
[image: Updated Size]
[image: Change Size]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLayeredPane lp;
        private ImagePane imagePane;
        private GridPane gridPane;

        public TestPane() throws IOException {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            lp = new JLayeredPane();
            lp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            imagePane = new ImagePane();
            gridPane = new GridPane();

            gridPane.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 64));
            imagePane.setImg(ImageIO.read(...)));

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            lp.add(imagePane, gbc);
            lp.add(gridPane, gbc);

            lp.setLayer(imagePane, 0);
            lp.setLayer(gridPane, 10);

            lp.setBackground(Color.RED);
            lp.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 0.85;
            gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;

            add(lp, gbc);

            applyDesiredSize(200, 200);

            JButton btn = new JButton("Change");

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 0.25;
            add(btn, gbc);

            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JTextField widthTF = new JTextField(4);
                    JTextField heightTF = new JTextField(4);

                    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                    panel.add(new JLabel("Size: "));
                    panel.add(widthTF);
                    panel.add(new JLabel("x"));
                    panel.add(heightTF);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, panel, "Change Size", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

                    try {
                        int width = Integer.parseInt(widthTF.getText());
                        int height = Integer.parseInt(heightTF.getText());
                        applyDesiredSize(width, height);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Invalid dimensions", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        protected void applyDesiredSize(int width, int height) {
            Dimension size = new Dimension(width, height);
//          lp.setPreferredSize(size);
            imagePane.setPreferredSize(size);
            gridPane.setPreferredSize(size);

            // Stop GridBagLayout from shrinking the components
            imagePane.setMinimumSize(size);
            gridPane.setMinimumSize(size);

            lp.revalidate();
            lp.repaint();
        }

    }

    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;

        public ImagePane() {
        }

        public BufferedImage getImg() {
            return img;
        }

        public void setImg(BufferedImage img) {
            this.img = img;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class GridPane extends JPanel {

        private int gridSize = 10;

        public GridPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        public int getGridSize() {
            return gridSize;
        }

        public void setGridSize(int gridSize) {
            this.gridSize = gridSize;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(getForeground());
            for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x += gridSize) {
                g2d.drawLine(x, 0, x, getHeight());
            }
            for (int y = 0; y < getWidth(); y += gridSize) {
                g2d.drawLine(0, y, getWidth(), y);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

So, before you shoot me down because it "doesn't fit with what you've done", understand that:

- I've no context to go on as to what you've actually done, other then an overview of your problem description
- I've provided a runnable example which demonstrates the basic concepts you "might" be able to use to solve your issue, which is more then you've done for us
- This is not the only way you might achieve this, and by no means is it my preferred solution

Comment: Thank you. :) It's exactly what I was looking for. Even if it doesn't fit to my code, I just wanted an example to show me a way to solve my problem.